# How do you find your insured car?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I started *GTA Online* and found a Futo and brought it to LS customs and put insurance and tracker on it. I saved and ended the game and when I turned it back on, I don't know how to find my car again.

**How do I locate the insured, tracked car?**

Answer (score 2):

The tracker puts a marker on the map, similar to the icon used for the Impound in offline player.

I believe the marker is called "Personal Vehicle" on the legend, so you should be able to find it fairly quickly.

Alternatively, if the marker isn't visible on the map, use your phone to call the insurance company and request a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the insurance company using your mobile phone. You can find the number under "Contacts".

Comment: If the car isn't on the map and the insurance contact is not on the phone, then the car has been lost to the cloud servers forever.  GTA Online is getting better about this, but it can still happen from time to time.